# Extended property disappears after sending the messages in Outlook for Mac

Tags: office365, outlook-web-addins, outlook-restapi

I am developing an Office Add-in for MAC outlook client. I want to set the extended property (X-header). This extended property is successfully created after executing the following REST call:

```
var propId="String {00020386-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} Name x- 
Test1";
var msgSendAs= {"SingleValueExtendedProperties": [       {
          "PropertyId": propId,
          "Value": f }]};
msgSendAs = JSON.stringify(msgSendAs);
$.ajax({
url: patchMessageUrl,  type : 'PATCH',  
data : msgSendAs,
headers:{'Authorization':'Bearer '+accessToken,'Content- 
Type':'application/json','x-AnchorMailbox': _anchor }
}).done(function(response) 
{
  ...
```

Problem: if I send a message then X-header disappears. I do not see it on receiver's end.

The same code works fine in Outlook on the web.

Comment: Are you trying to execute this given code from a Outlook Web Addin?

Comment: Yes I'm trying to execute this code from an Outlook Web add-in.

Comment: Did you consider using Internet Headers API from Outllook Extensibility? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.internetheaders?view=outlook-js-preview

Comment: Thanks, I know about Internet Headers API. As far as I understand this API is still in preview step, correct? My inital question was: why this code doesn't work on Outlook for Mac? Could you please answer.

Comment: Outlook Add-ins Team - MSFT, could you please reply?

Comment: No help anymore?

Comment: There is an issue we are trying to fix at our end. We request you to use the Internet Headers API provided by office.js. This API is moving out of preview and will be available soon.